# AgeCalendar Datetime Field Issue

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012, calendar, conditional-statements, case-when

For my AgingCalendar field, I have 3 conditions using CASE WHEN:

```
    CASE WHEN A.[END_DTTM] > A.[STRT_DTTM] THEN C2.[DY_OF_CAL_NUM] - C1.[DY_OF_CAL_NUM] 
         WHEN A.[END_DTTM] IS NULL and A.[STRT_DTTM] IS NOT NULL THEN C3.[DY_OF_CAL_NUM] - C1.[DY_OF_CAL_NUM]
         WHEN A.[END_DTTM] = A.[STRT_DTTM] THEN 1
    END AS AgeCalendar
```

For my third condition, I'm trying to basically say when the End Datetime = Start Datetime, the age in Calendar days should be set to 1 calendar day.

However, in some of the records I'm bringing in, the start date equals the end date, but the times associated with each datetime are different. When this happens, those records are receiving a NULL in the AgeCalendar field.(For example I could have 6/6/2014 0:00:00 = 6/6/2014 0:00:00, and that will give me 1...but if I had 6/6/2014 0:00:00 = 6/6/2014 0:03:59 (or something like that)...it'll give me a NULL value because it's not matching.
  How can I update the code above so that I'm basically saying when End Date = Start Date, then 1...regardless of not having matching times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CAST`or `CONVERT` them as dates to ignore the time.

`WHEN CONVERT(DATE, A.[END_DTTM]) = CONVERT(DATE, A.[STRT_DTTM]) THEN 1`

OR

`WHEN CAST(A.[END_DTTM] AS DATE) = CAST(A.[STRT_DTTM] AS DATE) THEN 1`

Comment: I knew it had to be simple, but was drawing a blank. Thank you @scsimon.